# ClassCastException when saving record in HSQLDB

Tags: java, hsqldb, activejdbc

I'm trying to migrate test DB from Oracle to HSQLDB. In Oracle I have fields with type NUMERIC (x,0). As I know NUMERIC type associated with BigDecimal java type. And when I run my tests and try to save record in DB I have the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
```

If I change type from NUMERIC(x,0) to INTEGER it work's correctly. But INTEGER type not support precision and scale in HSQLDB.

Is there the way to fix this problem?

**UPDATED:**

```
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.DB.execInsert(DB.java:521)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.insert(Model.java:2096)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.save(Model.java:2008)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.saveIt(Model.java:1935)
    at org.javalite.activejdbc.Model.createIt(Model.java:1625)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
    ... 41 more
```

I'm using ActiveJDBC

```
public class Employee extends Model {...}

Employee e = (Employee) Employee.createIt("e_type", 1, "name", "Employee")
```

Comment: @Nastya- you are trying to convert Integer number into a BigDecimal number. use BigDecimal instead of Integer to resolve this.

Comment: here: http://database-management.softwareinsider.com/l/15/HSQLDB you can look up what datatypes hsqldb supports

Comment: HSQLDB supports NUMERIC. Add to your question the code that you use to save the INTEGER and the top lines from the full stack trace.

Comment: @Nastya, please, include a full stack trace, schema of your table and a snippet of code you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of HSQLDB (2.3.4) supports NUMERIC(x,0) and also supports PreparedStatement setInt(), setBigDecimal() and setObject() with Java Integer values on columns that are defined as NUMERIC(x,0). So the error message looks impossible

These are the possibilities to work around this:

1. add `;sql.syntax_mys` to your HSQLDB connection URL and use `INTEGER(n)` which is a MySQL type
2. add `;sql.syntax_ora` to your HSQLDB connection URL and use `NUMBER(n)` which is the Oracle type
3. alternatively use `createIt("e_type", 1.0, "name", "Employee")` or createIt("e_type", "1", "name", "Employee") if it is accepted by ActiveJDBC
4. ask ActiveJDBC to add support for HSQLDB. This should be pretty easy for them to do.

Comment: ActiveJDBC is a pass-through model: http://javalite.io/pass_through_framework. It will gladly pass whatever type you give it to stack below. The same is true when loading data from a table. I think your advice is solid.